# Aggregating the total count with Json Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an API endpoint which has the details of confirmed / recovered / tested count for each state

```
https://data.covid19india.org/v4/min/data.min.json
```

I would like to to aggregate the total count of confirmed / recovered / tested across each state.. What is the easiest way to achieve the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, my interpretation was incorrect earlier. We have to get the districts total and add them.

```
import json

file = open('data.min.json')

dictionary = json.load(file)

stateCodes = ['AN', 'AP', 'AR', 'AS', 'BR', 'CH', 'CT', 'DL', 'DN', 'GA', 'GJ', 'HP', 'HR', 'JH', 'JK', 'KA', 'KL', 'LA', 'LD', 'MH', 'ML', 'MN', 'MP', 'MZ', 'NL', 'OR', 'PB', 'PY', 'RJ', 'SK', 'TG', 'TN', 'TR', 'TT', 'UP', 'UT', 'WB']

StateWiseData = {}

for state in stateCodes:
    StateInfo = dictionary[state]
    Confirmed = 0
    Recovered = 0
    Tested = 0
    Deceased = 0
    StateData = {}
    
    if "districts" in StateInfo:
        for District in StateInfo['districts']: 
            DistrictInfo = StateInfo['districts'][District]['total']
            if 'confirmed' in DistrictInfo:
                if type(Confirmed) == type(DistrictInfo['confirmed']):
                    Confirmed += (DistrictInfo['confirmed'])
            
            if 'recovered' in DistrictInfo:
                if type(Recovered) == type(DistrictInfo['recovered']):
                    Recovered += (DistrictInfo['recovered'])         
            
            if 'tested' in DistrictInfo:
                if type(Tested) == type(DistrictInfo['tested']):
                    Tested += (DistrictInfo['tested'])
            
            if 'deceased' in DistrictInfo:
                if type(Deceased) == type(DistrictInfo['deceased']):
                    Deceased += (DistrictInfo['deceased'])
            
    StateData['confirmed'] = Confirmed
    StateData['deceased'] = Deceased
    StateData['recovered'] = Recovered
    StateData['tested'] = Tested
    
    StateWiseData[state] = StateData
        
print(StateWiseData)
```

Comment: The count seems incorrect.. For example for the AN, the confirmed cases as on date is 7557.. But as per your script, it gives only 15  as count in Confirmed.

Comment: Ok then my interpretation is incorrect. I will rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

To write the final results in pandas we can procede by adding this to the code.

```
import Pandas as Pd

columns = ('Confirmed', 'Deceased', 'Recovered', 'Tested')  

Panda = pd.DataFrame(data = StateWiseData).T # T for transpose

print(Panda)
```

The output will be:

```
    confirmed  deceased  recovered    tested
AN       7557       129       7420         0
AP    2003342     13735    1975448   9788047
AR      52214       259      50695    398545
AS     584434      5576     570847    326318
BR     725588      9649     715798  17107895
CH      65066       812      64213    652657
CT    1004144     13553     989728    338344
DL    1437334     25079    1411881  25142853
DN      10662         4      10620     72410
GA     173221      3186     169160         0
GJ     825302     10079     815041  10900176
HP     211746      3553     206094    481328
HR     770347      9667     760004   3948145
JH     347730      5132     342421    233773
JK     324295      4403     318838    139552
KA    2939767     37155    2882331   9791334
KL    3814305     19494    3631066   3875002
LA      20491       207      20223    110068
LD      10309        51      10194    234256
MH    6424651    135962    6231999   8421643
ML      74070      1281      69859         0
MN     111212      1755     105751     13542
MP     792101     10516     781499   3384824
MZ      52472       200      46675         0
NL      29589       610      27151    116359
OR    1001698      7479     986334   2774807
PB     600266     16352     583426   2938477
PY     122934      1808     120330    567923
RJ     954023      8954     944917   5852578
SK      29340       367      27185         0
TG     654989      3858     644747         0
TN    2600885     34709    2547005   4413963
TR      82092       784      80150    607962
TT          0         0          0         0
UP    1709119     22792    1685954  23724581 
UT     342749      7377     329006   2127358
WB    1543496     18371    1515789         0
```

Comment: Awesome.. Can't we give State as the column name infront of the first column?

Comment: It will not come on the top of keys. Instead we need to add a column with the state names. We can do it while initiating the statewisedata dictionary. And then then adding the state element in the columns tuple. BTW please upvote.